# JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory while configuring Jenkins to compile the git project

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins

Getting the following error in Jenkins, while compiling the code:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory. 
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Users\admin\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK" 
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the 
location of your Java installation.
```

In the Environment variable, i have set the JAVA_HOME as:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45
```

In Jenkins , under Build section , I have set the goal as "compile"
for "Invoke top level Maven targets".

Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Comment: What does `echo %JAVA_HOME%` show you from the command line?  If that looks right, then the next place to check is a script which is perhaps overwriting this value.

Comment: echo %JAVA_HOME% is returning the correct value:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45

Comment: I don't know Jenkins well enough to be of any more help.  Try checking the build script and see where the `hudson.model.JDK` is coming from.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that Jenkins when installed as a service over-rides the set JAVA_HOME system environment variable and sets itself to JRE that came with Jenkins installation. So all Java Builds fail, as this requires JDK

The solution that worked for us is, we had to configure JAVA_HOME environment variable in `Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Global Properties`

[image]

Comment: After expending some hours, this solution worked for me, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

try to add this command in "Path" in Environment variable
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%JAVA_HOME%\bin